# Can we create constructor and methods in a single class.?

Tags: java, oop, constructor, automation

I am trying to define Constructor and method in s single class and accessing it from main class method. But I am getting error "The constructor ConstructorConcept() is undefined"  when I try to invoke the method read() as below. 
My question is, this is how we usually create object for a class and access its properties. Then, why it is showing error while accessing read() method?
Can't we define methods and Constructors in a single class?

```
public class ConstructorConcept {

    String Location;
    String StateName;
    int CityCounts;
    int m=10, n=20;
    int sum;

    public void read() {
        sum=m+n;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    ConstructorConcept (String a,String b,int x)
    {
        this.StateName=a;
        this.Location=b;
        this.CityCounts=x;
    }

    ConstructorConcept (String i,String j)
    {
        this.StateName=i;
        this.Location=j;
    }

}


public class ConstructorMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ConstructorConcept v1=new ConstructorConcept("Victoria","Australia",12);
        ConstructorConcept v2= new ConstructorConcept ("VIC", "AUS");
        System.out.println(v1.StateName+ " " +v1.Location+ " " +v1.CityCounts);
        System.out.println(v2.StateName+ " " +v2.Location);

        ConstructorConcept v3= new ConstructorConcept();            
        v3.read();
        System.out.println(v3.m);                               
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error output?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line

`ConstructorConcept v3= new ConstructorConcept();`

You are invoking an empty contstructor here, which doesn't exist in the ConstructorConcept class. Add this constrcutor declaration inside your ConstructorConcept class and it will work:-

```
ConstructorConcept(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

V3 is wrong you don't have an constructor without arguments. The other instantiations are working for me.

You can add a new Constructor without any parameter or you add the missing values in the instantiation of v3

Answer (score 0):

Standard Java Pojo has limitations for it's filed to be accessed by others. `public`, `default`, `private`.
And you need a default `constructor` since you already have your own contractors. If you don't have any `constrcutors`, the default contractor is automatically added.
 In your situation, I think the below code is more appropriate:

```java
public class ConstructorConcept {

    String Location;
    String StateName;
    int CityCounts;
    int m=10, n=20;
    int sum;

    public void read() {
        sum=m+n;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    ConstructorConcept (String a,String b,int x)
    {
        this.StateName=a;
        this.Location=b;
        this.CityCounts=x;
    }

    ConstructorConcept (String i,String j)
    {
        this.StateName=i;
        this.Location=j;
    }

    //you need all the getters/setters to access fields
    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        Location = location;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return StateName;
    }

    public void setStateName(String stateName) {
        StateName = stateName;
    }

    public int getCityCounts() {
        return CityCounts;
    }

    public void setCityCounts(int cityCounts) {
        CityCounts = cityCounts;
    }

    public int getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(int m) {
        this.m = m;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public void setSum(int sum) {
        this.sum = sum;
    }
    // you need a default Constructor
    public ConstructorConcept() {
    }
}


public class ConstructorMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        ConstructorConcept v1=new ConstructorConcept("Victoria","Australia",12);
        ConstructorConcept v2= new ConstructorConcept ("VIC", "AUS");
        System.out.println(v1.getStateName()+ " " +v1.getLocation()+ " " +v1.getCityCounts());
        System.out.println(v2.getStateName()+ " " +v2.getLocation());

        ConstructorConcept v3= new ConstructorConcept();
        v3.read();
        System.out.println(v3.m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can define methods and constructors in a single class.
As I can see your code , you are trying to Instantiating an object while the zero argument constructor which is not present in your class ConstructorConcept write that constructor before calling the read method.